# cart.save() is not a function for updating a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating an ecommerce app in which I am currently working on cart using mongoDb and coding in nodejs. I have tried a lot but cart.save() is not a function error is being raised. Below is my
**cartModel.js**
import mongoose from "mongoose"
const cartSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
user: {
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
required: true,
ref: "User",
},
cartItems: [
{
name: { type: String, required: true },
qty: { type: Number, required: true },
image: { type: String, required: true },
price: { type: Number, required: true },
countInStock: { type: Number, required: true },
product: {
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
required: true,
ref: "Product",
},
},
],
},
{
timestamps: true,
}
)
const cartModel = mongoose.model("Cart", cartSchema)
export default cartModel

and **cartController.js**

```
export const addToCart = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { cartItems } = req.body
  if (cartItems && cartItems.length === 0) {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error("No item in the cart")
  } else {
    const cart = await Cart.find({ user: req.user._id })
    if (cart && cart.length !== 0) {
      cart.cartItems = [...cartItems]

      const updatedCart = await cart.save()
      res.status(201)
      res.json(updatedCart)
    } else {
      const newCart = new Cart({
        user: req.user._id,
        cartItems,
      })
      const updatedCart = await newCart.save()
      res.status(201)
      res.json(updatedCart)
    }
  }
})
```

When I try to update it using following object

```
{
    "cartItems":[
        {
            "name":"Ring",
            "qty":"1",
            "image":"ring-image",
            "price":"160",
            "countInStock": 5,
            "product": "60ff8222ce6dca3378449b93"
        },{
            "name":"Wallet",
            "qty":"2",
            "image":"wallet-image",
            "price":"40",
            "countInStock": 16,
            "product": "60ff8222ce6dca3378449b93"
        }
    ]
}
```

It gives me error that cart.save() is not a function. I don't know what I am doing wrong because newCart.save() is running fine but, why cart.save() is raising an error?

Answer (score 0):

Error is that when we find in the cart using user._id, it returns an array so if we change

```
const cart = await Cart.find({ user: req.user._id })
```

to

```
const cart = (await Cart.find({ user: req.user._id }))[0]
```

it works fine then

Answer (score 0):

find() returns an array. You have to use findOne(), that returns a document.

```js
    const cart = await Cart.findOne({ user: req.user._id })
    await cart.save()
```